# Kendo UI pie chart: datasource transport read not fired and chart not displayed

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I have this code for displaying a kendo pie chart:

This is the div where the chart should be created:

```
  <div id="chart100Month" style="width:100%"></div>
```

This is javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

`function createChartMonth100() {`

```
$("#chart100month").kendoChart({
    dataSource: {
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "/getchartdatabytesttype100",
                dataType: "json"
            }
        },
        filter: {
            // field: "year", operator: "eq", value: year
        },
        sort: {

        }
    },
    title: {
        text: "test"
    },
    legend: {
        position: "top"
    },
    seriesDefaults: {
        type: "pie"
    },
    series: [{
            type: "pie",
            field: "percentage",
            categoryField: "type", }],
    tooltip: {
        visible: true,
        format: "N0",
        // template: "#= category # - #= kendo.format('{0:P}', percentage)#"
    }
});}
$(document).ready(createChartMonth100);
$(document).bind("kendo:skinChange", createChartMonth100);

</script>
```

This code is largely taken from the examples from telerik websites

The json array that /getchartdatabytesttype100 is:

```
[{"percentage":0,"type":"hypo"},{"percentage":66.666666666667,"type":"normal"},{"percentage":16.666666666667,"type":"lighthyper"},{"percentage":16.666666666667,"type":"hyper"}]
```

Chart is not rendered and firebug shows that the get request for the datasource read is not fired.

Any suggestions?

Paolo

Comment: you have typo  $("#chart100month"). should be  $("#chart100Month")

Comment: Many thanks Gene. I did not see this typo. Chart is now working good!